# Custom bar button item not detecting touch correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have created two custom buttons in the nav bar's right bar button using storyboard like so:

[image]

Below is how they look. I've added background colours to the buttons for easy viewing of detectable area.

[image]

The problem I am having is that the map button on the right is only detecting touch events on the left side of the button. The left button is detecting touch events fine. What's even stranger is that it seems to work fine in the simulator, but not on devices. I've tried on multiple devices and they all have the same issue. This is driving me crazy.... been at it all day. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the wall for two days with this one, I finally realised that as of Xcode 7 you can finally just drag multiple UIBarButtonItems to the UINavigationItem directly in Interface Builder. Creating the two buttons this way instead of the previous method fixed the issue.